# How to resize only 1 part of a SVG in order to fill the content

Tags: css, svg

I understand that SVG actually doesn't have a content, but I am struglying with this problem and I can't solve during days.

I have a Figma (so I can get the SVG) with this design:

[image]

The problem is that "Your Collection" text needs to grow to the right in some situations, for example: When I translate the app to Spanish and I have to show: "Tu Coleccion", or some other languages with even longer texts.

In the Figma that shape is made by 2 shapes + an "UNION" rule from Figma:

```css
body { background-color: #7fb6ff80;}
```

```html
<svg width="188" height="71" viewBox="0 0 188 71" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <mask id="path-1-inside-1_193_1631" fill="white">
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M72.3203 50.6719C68.8459 50.6719 65.7635 52.7341 63.7839 55.5894C57.4655 64.7034 46.9298 70.6719 35 70.6719C15.67 70.6719 0 55.0019 0 35.6719C0 16.342 15.67 0.671936 35 0.671936C46.9298 0.671936 57.4655 6.64051 63.7839 15.7544C65.7635 18.6098 68.8459 20.6719 72.3203 20.6719H173C181.284 20.6719 188 27.3877 188 35.6719C188 43.9562 181.284 50.6719 173 50.6719H72.3203Z"/>
  </mask>
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M72.3203 50.6719C68.8459 50.6719 65.7635 52.7341 63.7839 55.5894C57.4655 64.7034 46.9298 70.6719 35 70.6719C15.67 70.6719 0 55.0019 0 35.6719C0 16.342 15.67 0.671936 35 0.671936C46.9298 0.671936 57.4655 6.64051 63.7839 15.7544C65.7635 18.6098 68.8459 20.6719 72.3203 20.6719H173C181.284 20.6719 188 27.3877 188 35.6719C188 43.9562 181.284 50.6719 173 50.6719H72.3203Z" fill="white"/>
  <path d="M63.7839 15.7544L62.9621 16.3242L63.7839 15.7544ZM62.9621 55.0197C56.8225 63.8757 46.588 69.6719 35 69.6719V71.6719C47.2715 71.6719 58.1085 65.531 64.6057 56.1592L62.9621 55.0197ZM35 69.6719C16.2223 69.6719 1 54.4496 1 35.6719H-1C-1 55.5542 15.1177 71.6719 35 71.6719V69.6719ZM1 35.6719C1 16.8943 16.2223 1.67194 35 1.67194V-0.328064C15.1177 -0.328064 -1 15.7897 -1 35.6719H1ZM35 1.67194C46.588 1.67194 56.8225 7.4682 62.9621 16.3242L64.6057 15.1847C58.1085 5.81283 47.2715 -0.328064 35 -0.328064V1.67194ZM72.3203 21.6719H173V19.6719H72.3203V21.6719ZM173 21.6719C180.732 21.6719 187 27.9399 187 35.6719H189C189 26.8354 181.837 19.6719 173 19.6719V21.6719ZM187 35.6719C187 43.4039 180.732 49.6719 173 49.6719V51.6719C181.837 51.6719 189 44.5085 189 35.6719H187ZM173 49.6719H72.3203V51.6719H173V49.6719ZM62.9621 16.3242C65.0754 19.3724 68.4347 21.6719 72.3203 21.6719V19.6719C69.2571 19.6719 66.4515 17.8471 64.6057 15.1847L62.9621 16.3242ZM64.6057 56.1592C66.4515 53.4968 69.2571 51.6719 72.3203 51.6719V49.6719C68.4347 49.6719 65.0754 51.9714 62.9621 55.0197L64.6057 56.1592Z" fill="#F2F2F2" mask="url(#path-1-inside-1_193_1631)"/>
</svg>
```

- Do you have any idea how could I change the width of that second part in order to fill the content, without changing the circle part?
- Do you have any idea how to get this with CSS (without SVG)? The harder part with CSS is the curve that is in the union between the circle and the rectangle. The other part is simple.

Comment: your jsfiddle link doesn't wort, and, biwise you MUST use stackoverflow snippet instead !

Comment: @MisterJojo done, my friend.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be a good idea to have a "sliding doors" effect. So, here I made patterns for both the circle and the "text label". Switching between patterns with different sizes makes the text label resize.

This can be done dynamically if you look for the size of the text and then update the pattern based on that.

```css
body { background-color: #7fb6ff80;}

svg {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0" viewBox="0 0 400 104" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <pattern id="circle" viewBox="0 0 104 104" width="100%" height="100%">
    <path transform="translate(2 2)" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="none"
    d="M 102 30 Q 97 30 92 23 Q 76 0 50 0 A 10 10 90 0 0 50 100 Q 76 100 92 77 Q 97 70 102 70"/>
  </pattern>
  <pattern id="p1_120" viewBox="0 0 400 104" width="100%" height="100%">
    <path transform="translate(120 2)" stroke="gray" stroke-width="2" fill="none"
    d="M -200 30 H 0 A 1 1 0 0 1 0 70 H -200"/>
  </pattern>
  <pattern id="p1_140" viewBox="0 0 400 104" width="100%" height="100%">
    <path transform="translate(140 2)" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="none"
    d="M -200 30 H 0 A 1 1 0 0 1 0 70 H -200"/>
  </pattern>
  <pattern id="p1_160" viewBox="0 0 400 104" width="100%" height="100%">
    <path transform="translate(160 2)" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="none"
    d="M -200 30 H 0 A 1 1 0 0 1 0 70 H -200"/>
  </pattern>
</svg>

<svg id="svg01" viewBox="0 0 400 104" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect x="104" width="400" height="104" fill="url(#p1_160)" />
  <rect width="104" height="104" fill="url(#circle)"/>
  <text x="110" y="53" dominant-baseline="middle" font-size="20"
  font-family="sans-serif">Your Collection</text>
</svg>

<svg id="svg02" viewBox="0 0 400 104" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect x="104" width="400" height="104" fill="url(#p1_140)" />
  <rect width="104" height="104" fill="url(#circle)"/>
  <text x="110" y="53" dominant-baseline="middle" font-size="20"
  font-family="sans-serif">Tu Coleccion</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: It is not a bad idea, but the problem are the letter size.
Each letter doesn't have the same length as others, (like "i" is smaller than "o").
The bigger problem will be with Chinese words. 1 letter uses the same space as 10, sometimes.
Your idea could work mainly for Latin charset, but my app is on Arabic, Latin, Chinese, Russian, and more  :(
I'm considering just implementing CSS and losing the curve between the circle and the rectangle. Will be fast, simple, and doesn't lose that much value